# HIVE - Issue in storing data

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive

I am using HIVE database and in one of the table, one of the column is DECIMAL(38,15). I am trying to load the data from a file where some of the values are 32 length long without any decimal places and some of the values have 15 points after the decimal. So, I can't change the datatype precision and scale. When I am trying to load the data, the values which are 32 length long are getting stored as NULL because 15 places are stored for decimal. I have googled with no success. I tried double datatype as well but some of the values are getting truncated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: store it as a `string` and do the manipulations later.

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala: Thanks, but that's not the choice I have at the moment.

Comment: Look at it this way.  You're landing raw data. You have no control over how it's coming in. The only way you can prevent this is to store everything as a string.

Comment: You cannot change the datatype in the target table and nor you can limit precision in the input data. But to solve a problem you need to change something. What else are you going to change then? Mission impossible?

Comment: @leftjoin: in the current scenario I am stuck with the DECIMAL(38,18) but I can change the datatype in target to solve the problem. Tell me which numeric datatype I can use or I can store the values in apart from string.

Comment: Why don't you post some sample data..

Comment: I don't understand what you have against using strings